# Another account under my website

Tags: cpanel, whm

Maybe this question has been asked before however i couldn't right words to search it.

I have a reseller account on Resellerzoom.com

Let's say i created an account www.testaccount.com (username testacc) on my reseller account.

And another user created www.anotheruseraccount.com (username auseracc) on his/her reseller account.

When i entered www.testaccount.com/~auseracc to browser www.anotheruuseraccount.com's content is displaying.

I tried this on cloud. And the same thing happened. Why does this happen?

I got warning from Google because of someone else's website. Google thought it's hosted in my account. Is same IP causing this?

Is there a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this issues because you have enable " mod_userdir " on your server, Please try to disable mod_userdir through WHM >> Security Center >> Apache mod_userdir Tweak

If you are unable to change this setting, Please contact your hosting provider and ask them to check this, They will disable this with root user.

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Apache+mod_userdir+Tweak